# Can't delete controls from secondary Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having problems with adding new forms. When I add a new Form to my existing one ([Like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=feAbtNyaOzs)) the second Form is an exact copy of the main one and its controls cant be deleted or edited. [Main form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQbJ5.png) [Secondary Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iw3S5.png)

This is the Designer for the 2nd form:

```
namespace ImageEditingAppV1
{
    partial class Form2
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Text = "Form2";
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

And this is the code it has (which is empty):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ImageEditingAppV1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to delete those controls or even better a way add empty Forms to my existing one?

Comment: "*add a new Form to my existing one*". What do you mean by that? You are adding a Form to another Form?

Comment: Yes. Basically i want to open a 2nd form when a button is clicked on the main form. This is how i do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=feAbtNyaOzs
However the 2nd form isnt empty and all the controls cant be deleted or edited which is the problem.

Comment: Note the padlock icon on the inherited controls.  The designer honors accessibility for them, default is *private* so you can't do anything with them.  Go back to the base form and change their Modifiers property to Protected or Public.   You can't "uninherit" controls so maybe you want to design these forms the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you added an inherited form, which is read only. Besides adding existing forms, there are three other options.

- New->Form
- New->New Item->Select - Form
- New->New Item->Select - Inherited Form

It appears you chose the latter. You should be able to simply delete it and create a new Form.

Comment: This is how I add a 2nd form: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=feAbtNyaOzs
I select the Form option, yet the the new form has the same controls the main one has and all controls are locked, cant be deleted/edited.

Answer (score 0):

By experimenting around a bit I found out why adding additional Forms to you main (with the method i mentioned above) produces forms identical to the original with controls that can't be edited or deleted.
The name of the original Form is the root of the problem. Originally when creating a new WinForm project the Form's default name is Form1. At some point I changed the name of the Form (for whatever reason) to simply "Form", removing the "1".
Reverting back to it's default name, Form1, allows me now to add additional Forms to my project and all of them are blank and ready for use.

Just in case someone out there runs to a similar problem.